# Function call ambiguity in templatized code

Tags: c++

Here is a (very distilled) use case and code example (sorry if it doesn't look too minimal, I couldn't figure out what else to exclude. The complete 'just compile' code can be found here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5GMEGKG7T)

I want to have a "special" output stream, which, for certain user types, does special treatment during stream processing.

This special stream should be able to stream a "special" type with "special" treatment, as well as any other type which could be streamed through conventional streams - in the latter case, we simply use the conventional stream directly

```
struct Type { }; // Special type

struct Stream { // Special stream

    // In this distilled example, we could achieve the same result
    // by overriding << for ostream and Type, but the actual use case is wider
    // and requires usage of the special stream type
    // For illustration purposes only, we use this overload to cout "T!" for Types
    Stream& stream(Type t) { std::cout << "T!"; return *this;}

    // For any type for which cout << T{} is a valid operation, use cout for streaming       
    template<class T>
    auto stream(const T& t) -> decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>(), std::declval<Stream&>())
    {
        std::cout << t; return *this;
    }
};

// Consumes every T for which Stream.stream is defined - those would be Type
// as well as anything else which can be sent to cout
template<class T>
auto operator<<(Stream& s, const T& t) -> decltype(s.stream(t))
{
    s.stream(t);
    return s;
}
```

This code works as expected:

```
void foo()
{
    Stream stream;
    stream << 10 << Type{};
}
```

Now I want to define a different struct, which has a member of `Type` in it, and a streaming operator for the same struct:

```
struct Compound {
    Type t;
    int i;
};

// We want the `<<` operator of the struct templated, because we want it to work with 
// any possible stream-like object out there 
template<class S>
S& operator<<(S& s, Compound comp)
{
    s << comp.t << " " << comp.i;

    return s;
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work well. An attempt to use this `<<` operator:

```
void bar(Compound comp)
{
    Stream s;
    s << comp;
}
```

Triggers an ambiguity:

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand
> types are 'Stream' and 'Compound')

> note: candidate: 'decltype (s.Stream::stream(t)) operator<<(Stream&, const T&)

> note: candidate: 'S& operator<<(S&, Compound) [with S = Stream]'

That makes sense, since after defining templated operator for `<<` for `Compound`, it could be streamed via cout, as well as through this new operator!

I can certainly work aorund this by making `<<` for `Compound` non-templated, and instead use the special `Stream` as a stream argument - but I'd like to avoid it.

Is there a way I can preserve the templated `<<` for `Compound` and still avoid the ambiguity?

Comment: If you can't make a minimal example, can you make it complete? Something we can build on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ as is?

Comment: What C++ version?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is complete with the latest edit. As for version, any?

Comment: Ok, assuming C++20 then. What I meant is, it would be great to be able to copy it into a compiler as is. Without adding headers or combining several snippets.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat added link to godbolt as well.

Comment: @DrewDormann I have linked the fully complete version as well.

Comment: Do you want that `template<class S> S& operator<<(S& s, Compound comp)` is also directly useable, or useable only in the context of your special "stream" machinery? If it's the later, you might have some luck replacing that method with a template class for which you can define a partial specialization for `Compound`.

Comment: @user2407038 ideally, the former. If I am to go with the latter, I will just use Stream directly.

Comment: `int x=4;x << Compound{}` seems like a bad overload.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont not ideal - but will do for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to lower the priority of `operator<<(Stream& s, const T& t)` to make it the last resort.

You can do it by making it (seemingly) less specialized, by templating the first parameter:

```
auto operator<<(std::same_as<Stream> auto &s, const auto &t) -> decltype(s.stream(t))
{
    s.stream(t);
    return s;
}
```

The change I made to the second parameter is unimportant, it's just for terseness.

Comment: Note that this is not just sugar, but a decision.  It now routes to `s.stream(comp.t);s.stream(" "); s.stream(comp.i);` and not `s.stream(comp);`, which is what youpd get if `<<` for compound was lower - the overload priority matters.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not sure I fully understood your comment here. Care to elaborate in an answer what are the implications here?

Comment: @SergeyA When you do `Stream << Compound`, is it done via calling `s.stream(c)` or via `s << c.t << " " << c.i` which then calls `s.stream(c.t); s.stream(" "); s.stream(c.i);`.  How you arrange for the conflicting overloads to be resolved changes which way it goes.  The overload ambiguity here **is fundamental**, not a case where you don't care which way it goes.  This is also a red flag; the two `operator<<` do different things, and it isn't obvious which one is right, and difficult for users to understand which is called regardless.  Operators should have clear meaning; yours cannot.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont well, the point is that `s.stream(c)` is really not available unless there is a defined operator `stream << c`. The problem is that once the defined operator is created, it is becoming viable for `s.stream(c)` (which should actually never be selected, because it will trigger self-selection recursion).

Answer (score 0):

Some extra boilerplate maybe?

```cpp
template<class T> struct IsDefault: std::true_type {};
template<class T> concept Default = IsDefault<T>::value;

struct Stream {
    template<Default T> Stream &operator<<(T &&t) {
        return std::cout << t, *this;
    }
};

struct Compound {};
template<> struct IsDefault<Compound>: std::false_type {};
Stream &operator<<(Stream &s, Compound &&c) { return s << "Compound"; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to special-treat the `Compound` here. If I am to special-treat it, I would just define it's `<<` as accepting `Stream`. The idea was to make all this streaming business transparent to `Compound`.